# resizing JButton and icon at the same time fails. Only icon size is increased

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I'm trying to resize a `JButton`. I'm also trying to resize the image icon when the button is resized. I've used the `ComponentListener`. Here is the snippet of code trying to resize the image icon when the button size is increased:

```
jButton1.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        // ignore
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        Image newImg = img.getScaledInstance( jButton1.getWidth(), jButton1.getWidth(),  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ) ;
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(newImg);
        jButton1.setIcon(icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        // ignore
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        // ignore
    }
});
```

But the problem is that only icon size is increased. Though the width is taken from the button itself. The button size stays fixed. If I do not change the icon, button size is increased accordingly.

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: You may need to `revalidate` the parent. Try using something like `jButton1.getParent().revalidate()` for example.  This will also depend on the layout manager you are using.

Comment: It seems that issue is around revalidate. setIcon seems to call revalidate. If I call revalidate then my jButton does not get resized even without icon.

Comment: I've changed the layout to null layout from grid layout. It seems to have solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, that's not a particular good solution, something like GridBagLayout might be a better solution...

Comment: *"I've changed the layout to null layout.."*  I'll go further than @MadProgrammer to point out that is an *horrid* solution that will cause more problems than it creates.  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Comment: The test code can be found there [link](http://pastebin.com/Q5dMKzSQ)